# Naive object recognition based on laser sensor

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, I want to use the RaySensor plugin to get the id of the nearest object each ray intersect (instead of the range). I saw the GetFiducial() function, but don't know if it provides this information, could anybody tell me?.

If not, I've seen that the RayShape class has a GetIntersection() function, which I think that returns the information I need. But it would be grand not to have to build a new RaySensor based of RayShape.

Before I discovered this Gazebo forum I posed this same question in the ros answers forum:

[link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/47245/gazebo-naive-object-recognition-based-on-laser-sensor/)

, but I think that it fix better here, that's why I'm repetting it.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/128/naive-object-recognition-based-on-laser-sensor/) by [ercarrion43](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/72/ercarrion43/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The laser fiducial interface needs to be fixed. I have create a ticket for it
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/217/laser-fiducial-broken

You can set the retro value for a collision object, and read that back from the laser data.
SDF: http://gazebosim.org/sdf/1.2.html#laser_retro

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0